# Summary for a group of features in Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, bdd

What is the best way to provide a description for a group of features in Cucumber?
For example, I have a folder "login" for a group that contains the features:

- "loginForm.feature"
- "recoveryPassword.feature"
- "facebookLogin.feature"

How can I add an overarching description that summarizes the business case for "login" in general and that applies to all of these separate features? Can such a description be picked up by the processing tools without repeating it in each of the individual feature files?

Comment: Excellent Question! I have been using Cucumber ever since it was introduced and I still haven't found a way to do this! I don't think there exists any simple solution to do this.

Comment: I am glad, that I am not the only one! What kind of work arounds did you try ?

Comment: Well I just accepted the fact that it's not possible and try to include all scenarios related to same feature under a single feature files. So, all SSO (Single Sign On) scenarios will be under sso.feature even though that means fitting 200+ scenarios in a single file.

Comment: Looks like there is no solution, but to extend cucumber in some way or use a work around like Thakkar mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

One way of providing a simple description to a group of features is to tag them (see the documentation [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags)) e.g.

```
@Login
Feature: Login form

...

@Login
Feature: Password recovery

...

@Login
Feature: Facebook login

...
```

By using tags you can group together features (in the above example all features have the same "@Login" tag, where "Login" was chosen as it succinctly describes the main business case for all these features), and you can make the tag as descriptive/verbose as you want.

You can then instruct Cucumber to only run tests with the "@Login" tag, which is really useful if you want to test related features which are spread over multiple files.

Comment: The problem is that i could not find a way to associate a description to a tag. While the name can convey some information, i would to attach longer descriptions to a tag or folder.

Comment: True, but the tagging solution is a great compromise. I'd say that the feature descriptions within the files have the greatest value; the feature group description will be useful, but really it's just going to be a meta-descriptor.